# How to use downloadable fonts with support library?

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-downloadable-fonts

I'm trying to use downloadable fonts introduced in API 26 and apparently backward compatible with API 14 when the support library is used. How do I use it, though?

Using `android:fontFamily` causes Android Studio to show a warning and the fonts are not applied on API < 16:

> android:fontFamily requires API level 16 (current min is 14)

When `app:` namespace is used as [the documentation says](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib), the build fails with

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:fontFamily'.

I know that only about 1% of devices are running API < 16, but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @BenP. Android Studio 3.0.1